# How do I loop through user input with scanner and get max value with negative integers

Tags: java, for-loop, negative-number

I do not know how to make it so that my code can work with negative integers from user input any advice can help thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyScannerProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number ");
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            if (max < a) {
                max = a;
            }
            System.out.println("Your max is " + max);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: initialize `max` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: Also `if (max < a);` is wrong wrong wrong - remove the `;`

Answer (score 2):

There is a special constant value in Integer class, especially for this purpose. It stores the minimum value an Integer instance can store such that whenever you compare any possible int value with it, it will either be greater than or equal to it, never lesser.

```
public static final int   MIN_VALUE = 0x80000000;
```

In your program, if we simply initialize the **max** with this value instead of 0, it will start giving true for max

And of course, as @ScaryWombat told, get rid of the semi-colon after the if condition.

```
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number ");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        if (max < a) {
            max = a;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Your max is " +  max );
```

Comment: why does no-one do `max = Math.max(a, max)` ?

Comment: Yes sir @Scary Wombat, that'll be a better alternative since it is Mathematical.

Comment: @Yash It would be better if you explain why should one initialize to `Integer.MIN_VALUE;` and not `0`.

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik because if we initialize with 0, it will fail if all values are negative and always return 0 as the max value :)

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik I believe that yash did a good job explaining that in his first paragraph

Comment: Yes sir indeed... @ScaryWombat I just wanted to add `"when all inputs are negative"` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use initialization with the minimum number possible or simply take the first number as a minimum and after that compare that with subsequent  numbers that you take as input.

```
        int max = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number ");
        max = sc.nextInt();
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) { // 1 less than you would normally do 
            System.out.println("Please enter a number ");
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            if (max < a) {
                max = a;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Your max is " +  max );
```

If you look at this code...we can do it simply like this:-(Just a different and easier way to implement the idea I have shown earlier)

```
        int max = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { 
            System.out.println("Please enter a number ");
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            if(i == 0) max=a;
            if (max < a) {
                max = a;
           }
        }
        System.out.println("Your max is " +  max );
```

Also like many commented and answered you can use the `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to initialize `max`.This solution is just a different way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Do not think so `if (max < a);`

Comment: @ScaryWombat you have an eagle eye ! Didn't spot that `;`

Comment: @AxelH Wombat eye you insensitive clod

Comment: why the fluffing about with `max = sc.nextInt();` outside the loop?

Comment: @ScaryWombat.: Just used it to initilaize max..that would help solve the initlaize with minimum value

Comment: @ScaryWombat.: You can tell me what else I should add to modify the answer

Comment: Compare your answer with the answer from @Yash

Comment: @ScaryWombat.: Yes I missed the `;` but apart from that my method works too and yes I avoided the minimum initialization part. Please let me know if this is alright otherwise I don't want to contribute poor quality posts.

Comment: The `max = sc.nextInt();` before the `for` has no prompt so the use will not know what to do - to a user it may just appear to be hung.  **But** why even have this line.  Just loop 10 times, the same as @Yash

Comment: @ScaryWombat.: I see...I have given him an idea you know..thinking that it is showing the idea...and ofcourse we can do this in for loop..loop 10 times..distinguish first time and then assign it to `max` and then compare usually. I iwll edit this answer..thanks for letting me know

Comment: @ScaryWombat.: Edited..please check and let me know if there is something else I can do make it useful